# Making unification function

Tags: openlayers, union, optimization, jsts

Well i make a map with OpenLayers 4 in draw a a brunch of polygons and try to union them if they intersect.

i made this code :

```
    function unification(){

 var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
 var w=0;
 var z=0;
 var compteur = Object.size(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures());

for (w=0;w<compteur;w++){

    if (!vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0]){
    }
    else{

  var featureA = vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];
  var jstsGeomA = parser.read(featureA.getGeometry());
  for(z=0;z<compteur;z++){

    if (!vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[z+1]){
    }
    else{

      var featureB = vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[z+1];
      var jstsGeomB = parser.read(featureB.getGeometry());

      if (jstsGeomA != jstsGeomB ){
      var intersect = jstsGeomA.intersects(jstsGeomB);
      if (intersect){

        var union = jstsGeomA.union(jstsGeomB);
        featureA.setGeometry(parser.write(union));
        featureB.setGeometry(parser.write(union));
        vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[z+1]);
        vector_layer.setVisible(false);
        vector_layer.setVisible(true);
        //compteur++;
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

but when i use my fonction on several polygons the 4th is deleted simply without giving the union result in another.

anyone got an idea?

Finally i found an answer but it isn’t optimized.

```
function unification(){


  var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
  var a=0;
  var b=0;
  var compteur = Object.size(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures());
  var featureA ;
  var jstsGeomA ;
  var featureB ;
  var jstsGeomB ;
  var intersection ;

  for (a=0;a<compteur;a++){
if(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[a]){

  featureA = vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[a];
  jstsGeomA = parser.read(featureA.getGeometry());

  for(b=0;b<compteur;b++)
    if(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[b] ){
      if(a!=b){
      featureB = vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[b];
      jstsGeomB = parser.read(featureB.getGeometry());
      intersection = jstsGeomA.intersects(jstsGeomB);

      if (intersection){


          var union = jstsGeomA.union(jstsGeomB);
          var unionFinale = union.holes= [];//WTF?WTF?WTF???
          featureA.setGeometry(parser.write(union));
          featureB.setGeometry(parser.write(union));
          vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(featureB);
          a=0;
          compteur--;
          break;          
      }
    }
  }
}
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the exact polygons you are using to test?

Comment: i couldn't i make differents polygons each time, i draw them. i jus cross them for the union.

Comment: If you don't use consistent data, how are you going to debug?

Comment: well i make a list of user possible actions and i try them one by one to find bugs. I know it isn t optimized but i didn t know any better way to do it.